# Show featured item in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is more of a generalized approach question. I wanted to see if anyone could give me some pointers.

I'm making a rails app that will have a "featured item". This item will have a start date/time and an end date/time, and only one item will be within that time range (so, if today is within item X's range, item X is the current featured item).

For showing this in my View, would it be best just to show whichever one has a start date that's <= than today's date/time and end date that's >= than today's date/time, or is there a better way to approach it? Each item will have a picture and some text - nothing too fancy.

I'm looking forward to hearing your thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put the featured logic in your model. The time constraints you have sound good.  It is good to put the featured logic in your model because you can then make a validation that ensures that no item has a featured time range that overlaps another one.  Then in your view you could simply call something like `Post.get_featured` and that would get the current featured post.

Comment: Hey Michael, that sounds good. So, from what you're telling me, I should have a get_featured function in my post model. Within that, it'll iterate over every individual post, and conditionally just return whichever one is within the correct dates?

Comment: well you can run a query to see. So for instance in active record: Post.where(:featured_start_date < Date.today, :featured_end_date > Date.today).first